# How to get Record Owner ID from record ID?

Tags: controller, owner

I want to get the owner id/ user id of current record.

for this what I know, we have to do 2 things.
1) First we have to fetch record ID from URL by using

ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

2) We can fetch owner ID by using this record ID.

If I am correct then how to fetch record owner ID by using record ID?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you are correct .Just putting amswer into programmatic way

First get the Id in URL parameter and then on page fetch using

```
Id recId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
```

Secondly use Select statement and get the ownerId(Assuming object is Account)

```
 ID ownerId=[Select Id,ownerId from Account where Id=:recId].ownerId
```

Update:

After the comments looks like this has to be dynamic solution

```
id testid=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
String objecttype=testid.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();
try{
    Sobject s=(Database.query('Select Id,ownerId from '+objecttype+' where Id=:testid LIMIT 1'));
    }
catch(exception e){
    }
    Id ownerid=(ID)s.get('ownerId');
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohith Kumar. Here I am not going to use Account object, because I don't know from which object it will fetch record ID. It'll be decided during run time. I think we have to go for Dynamic SOQl. 
Correct me If I am wrong.
Regards

Comment: @Rudra_NoVoice Please find the updated response .I have updated the solution to be dynamic.Yes its Dynamic query but with little trick and advanced apex .Welcome to community:)

Comment: As a side note, you need to check to see if OwnerId exists before you attempt to query it. Child records in a master-detail relationship do not manifest an OwnerId field.

Comment: This is valid code: `Id ownerId, recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); try { ownerId = database.query('select id, ownerid from '+String.valueof(recordid.getsobjecttype())+' where id = '+string.escapesinglequotes(recordid)).ownerid; } catch(exception e) { };` At the end of the try-catch block, if ownerId != null, then we have a result.

Comment: @sfdcfox Good point to check if the ownerId field exits .Adding it to the answer :).Thanks

Comment: I actually kind of intended to mean check before querying, but a try-catch block would eliminate the problem anyways. And my code in the prior comment wasn't quite right, I noticed...

Comment: `Id ownerId, recordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); try { ownerId = database.query('select id, ownerid from '+String.valueof(recordid.getsobjecttype())+' where id = \''+string.escapesinglequotes(recordid)+'\'').get('OwnerId'); } catch(exception e) { };` -- this is the corrected version that I'd use in this exact scenario.

Comment: Hello @MohithKumar :
As you explained 
'Sobject s=(Database.query('Select Id,ownerId from '+objecttype+' LIMIT 1'));'
I think here we have to pass WHERE (Id) clause because if we will not pass then it will give us any random Record Details.
Can we do like below:
'Sobject s=(Database.query('SELECT Id,OwnerId FROM'+ objecttype +'WHERE Id='+ testid+'LIMIT 1'));'

Comment: @Rudra_NoVoice I have updated the answer and that should filter by ID